# Meaning of "docketed for requisition"

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

From *A History of Warfare* by John Keegan, [page 22](https://books.google.ru/books?id=LESvqQAqD9cC&lpg=PA22&ots=D7gFF4vuQ2&dq=%22docketed%20for%20requisition%22&hl=ru&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q=%22docketed%20for%20requisition%22&f=false):

> The regimental depots bulged with spare weapons and uniforms to kit the reservists out; even the horses in the farmers' fields were **docketed for requisition** should war come.

I found two [entries](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/docket) in Wiktionary that might be relevant:

> - An agenda of things to be done.
> - A ticket or label fixed to something, showing its contents or directions to its use.

Were the cattle physically equipped with tags (dockets), or were they included in some official documents specifying that they would be requisitioned in case of war?

Comment: I have a feeling that that "in the farmers' field" removes the ambiguity, I think the first interpretation is true. Why would the author want to mention "in the farmers' field"?

Comment: I think it means tagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this means that the horses were included on a list of things to be  requisitioned in case of war, so that horse-drawn transport would be fully equipped when called on.

As Nanigashi points out in a comment, "docketed" here is a from of "to docket", a transitive verb in this usage, and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/docket) gives as meaning 2:

> to make a brief abstract of (something, such as a legal matter) and inscribe it in a list

which is at least quite close to the meaning here.

Comment: I agree. It might be worth editing to point out that while the OP has cited two definitions of docket as a noun, it is used here as a verb, in roughly the sense covered by definition 2 under "transitive verb" at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/docket.

Comment: @Nanigashi Done.